# Change Connectortype in LibreOffice Draw

Tags: libreoffice-draw

Is there a way to change the connector type in LibreOffice Draw e.g. from a curved line to a straight line, or do I necessarily have to create a new connector?

Note, changing a single connector is just an example, eventually I want to change all the connectors I'm using in my diagram "in bulk" (e.g. by applying the change while more then one is selected).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the connector type:

1. Right click on the connector, select Connector.
2. On the Type category, select the type. Click OK.

[image]

[image]

For multiple connectors:

1. Select the connectors (hold Shift when selecting them).
2. Select Format -> Connector.
3. Select the connector type. Click OK.

Comment: Thanks, I was searching for over 30min already!

Comment: Just noticed, this only works for a single connector, is there a way to apply this when I have multiple connectors selected?

Comment: @Albin See edit.

Comment: Thats it, thank you!